# convert utf8 characters to binary

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing a project in nodeJS and I need to know how to convert utf8 characters to binary, there are some functions in JS that convert a good part of the characters but some are not possible, characters like `₢`.

Comment: *"...how to convert utf8 characters to binary..."* What does that mean? Can you give an example of your input and your expected output? Also, are you sure you're starting with UTF-8? If your data is in a JavaScript string, [it's in UTF-16](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) (allowing invalid surrogate pairs), but Node's [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) can copy data from strings into several encodings...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) SO is a **very** active place, even on the weekend. When you post a question (or answer), *stick around* for a few minutes to ensure that you can respond to requests for clarification.